How can I get warnings count for Rider C# project
I have a build shell script for my C# project. I want to add a specific logic to this script. This logic has to check if the count of warnings in my C# project is not greater than the count of warnings in this project in the previous commit.
For this purpose, I have to get a Rider(we use it as IDE in our company) warning count for specific C# projects from a shell script. How can I do this?
P.S. I don't need a solution for how to compare the got count with a count from the previous commit. I'll make it by myself. Just help me with getting the warnings count for a particular project from the terminal.

Simply enable MSBuild logging and parse the output, if you only need to count compiler generated warnings. But if you need to count ReSharper/Rider warnings in editors, I think they have a command line tool.
